# Go: How to define a linked list struct that can use different types

Tags: go, linked-list

The usual linked list structure is as follows：

```
type IntNode struct {
    Value  int
    Next   *IntNode
    Pre    *IntNode
}
```

but when i want value to be string, i need another struct:

```
type StringNode struct {
    Value string
    Next *StringNode
    Pre  *StringNode
}
```

I don't want to use interface{} to reduce the consumption of assertions. Is there a feasible way to write different types through a structure？

Answer (score 1):

Go 1.18 supports generics:

```golang
type LLNode[T any] struct {
    Value T
    Next  *LLNode[T]
    Prev  *LLNode[T]
}
```

So now you can use:

```golang
intList := &LLNode[int]{Value: 1}
stringList := &LLNode[string]{Value: "abcd"}
```

Comment: Currently using 1.17, is there a way to do this？

Comment: @Pccc With 1.17 you're out of luck. Upgrade to 1.18 or stick to `interface{}`.